# How can I link my selectInput to my DataTable to update the table based on the selections? (this is R Shiny)

Tags: jquery, r, shiny, datatable, datatables

Specifically, I'm using pickerInput (which is similar to selectInput), and a renderDataTable.

Here is what the app looks like (you can see where I'm trying to have the filter update the datatable - if i select 'setosa' the table should update to include just setosa rows):
[image]

Here is my minimally reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

results <- iris
results$Species <- as.character(results$Species)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel(
        h1("Iris Table", align="center")
    ),
    
    fluidRow(
        column(3,
               pickerInput("speciesInput", "Species", choices=unique(results$Species), options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), selected=NULL, multiple=TRUE)
        ),
        column(9, 
               DT::dataTableOutput('table')))
    
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
        DT::datatable(#filter='top',
            escape = FALSE,
            iris
        ))
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

results <- iris
results$Species <- as.character(results$Species)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel(
    h1("Iris Table", align="center")
  ),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           pickerInput("speciesInput", "Species", choices=unique(results$Species), options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE), selected=NULL, multiple=TRUE)
    ),
    column(9, 
           DT::dataTableOutput('table')))
  
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  mydata <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$speciesInput)) {df <- results
    } else df <- results[results$Species %in% input$speciesInput,]
    df
  })
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    datatable(mydata())
    )
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Perfect! Is there a way to expand this to have the reactive function work for multiple pickerInput filters? Say, for example, I had 3 pickerInputs instead of that 1 for species.

Comment: Sure.  Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242287/selectinput-filter-based-on-a-selection-from-another-selectinput-in-r).  You just need to replace `selectInput` by `pickerInput` and make some minor adjustments.

Comment: Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574600/r-shiny-updateselectinput-choices-for-one-dropdown-menu-with-choices-from-anothe) might be helpful.